# OLAP fact table empty records

Tags: data-warehouse, olap

I'm in the process of designing a fact table for olap lookups. Currently, I won't be allowing the user to run olap queries, like custom dimensions or slicing. I will be creating the queries myself to run specific reports.

My question is on the fact table for these reports. I want to avoid updating existing records, and just insert rows for multiple dimensions. For example:

Two inserts:

```
YEAR    AMOUNT
2016    1
2016    1
```

Instead of one insert, check if year=2016 exists, and if so then one update:

```
YEAR    AMOUNT
2016    2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/138409/fact-table-with-blank-dimensions/138515#138515

The issue I was facing was trying to put all facts into one table. I learned the best practice is to break up facts into different tables for different granularity, and limit columns to the minimal needed for the fact.

It's extra work inserting the data, but really pays off during retrieval which is the bulk of the database work.

Answer (score 0):

Use Upsert logic as below:

while inserting take inner join of source table with target table, on match update the amount field else insert the new records.

```
insert into target (select * from source s, target t where s.year <> t.year);

Update target T set T.amount = T.amount + S.amount 
from source S where T.year = S.year;
```